# Changing value of printed line

Tags: go, cmd

in my go-application which is cli-based I Need to update some values which are already printed. I already found a stackoverflow-question where I got to know that with `\r` the "Output-pointer" points to the first char of the former line, therefore overriding it. But multiple `\r`s arent working...
So how do I update e.g. the second line I printed.
Example:

```
#Id    #Name    #pwr    #dB
0      Name     unkn    -34
```

And I want to update those values without printing new lines

```
#Id    #Name    #pwr    #dB
0      NewName  45      -34
```

Comment: There is no "output pointer", perhaps you mean cursor position. A terminal prints a stream of output bytes. A linefeed (NL, `\n`, Ctrl+J) causes it to return to column zero and move to the next line. A carrage return (CR, `\r`, Ctrl+M) causes it to return to column zero. If you want to do anything more fancy you need to use something that queries the terminal capabilities to figure out the control codes it will respond to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do anything more than changing the current line, as you noticed, `\r` won't work. The solution is to set your terminal in a different mode which allow more control. However, this is painful to do by hand. Luckily, there are libraries out there that makes it easy. A very famous one is [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

For Go, [GoCUI](https://github.com/jroimartin/gocui) looks great. It should give you all the power you need with a nice interface.